# Incoming calls Moto X ; press 1 to accept call

Tags: calls, moto-x

For some reason my Moto X is requiring me to press the number 1 in order to accept incoming calls. I thought this may be a Motorola assist glitch, but the problem was not fixed when I disabled the application.

Any ideas? Similar problems out there?

Comment: Did you recently start using Google Voice, or turn on call screening?

Comment: @AlE. Yes, not recently, but I do have google voice. I have not intentionally turned on call screening. Any suggestions for settings I should change?

Comment: Check your [GV call settings](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0#callsettings) to ensure that call screening isn't on at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Press 1 to accept the call" sounds like Google Voice's call screening.

Check your [GV call settings](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0#callsettings) to ensure that call screening isn't on at all. (You can individually turn it off for certain people or groups, but the main setting would need to be "on".)

More on [Call Screening at Google Voice Support](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115083).

Comment: Also, if you pick up the call too fast, Google Voice's "press 1" prompt will appear regardless of the `Call Screening` setting.  According to Google, this is to prevent spamming by automated systems.